# Show that if $Y$ is $\sigma (X)-$ measurable, there is a measurable function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $Y=f(X)$.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Show that if $Y$ is $\sigma (X)-$measurable, there is a measurable function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $Y=f(X)$.

I really have problem to show that. It's clear that if $Y=f(X)$, then $Y$ is $\sigma (X)$ measurable. But the converse looks complicate.

**Attempt**

**Step 1 :** Let $Y=\boldsymbol 1_A$ for $A\in \sigma (X)$. In particular, there is a $B\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R):=\{borel\ set\ of\ \mathbb R\}$ s.t. $$X^{-1}(B)=A. $$ If I set, $$f(x)=\boldsymbol 1_B(x),$$
then $$Y(\omega )=\boldsymbol 1_A(\omega )=\boldsymbol 1_{X^{-1}(B)}(\omega )=\boldsymbol 1_{B}(X(\omega ))=f(X(\omega )).$$

**Step 2 :** If $Y$ is simple, the same argument work.

**Step 3 :** If $Y$ is positive, there is a sequence $Y_n$ of simple function s.t. $Y_n\nearrow Y$. Let $(f_n)_n$ s.t. $$Y_n=f_n(X).$$
Since $Y_n$ are a.s. increasing, $(f_n(X(\omega ))_n$ is a.s. increasing. But how can I prove that is converge to $f(X(\omega ))$ for some measurable $f$ ? I just have that $(f_n(X(\omega )))_n$ converge to $f(X(\omega ))=Y(\omega )$, but it doesn't tell me that the function $f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ obtained is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Consider $f(x) := \liminf_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$.

Comment: @saz: Thanks for your answer. So as you defined it, $f$ is measurable. Now, $Y(\omega )=\lim_{n\to \infty } f_n(X(\omega ))=\liminf_{n\to \infty }f_n(X(\omega ))=f(X(\omega ))$. Is it working ? Would it work with $g(x)=\limsup_{n\to \infty }f_n(x)$ ?

Comment: "Yes" to both of your question

Comment: The reason you have to use $\liminf f_n$ is that $\lim f_n(x)$ is only guaranteed to exist when $x=X(\omega)$ for some $\omega$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: Yes thank you. I was just confuse on "why $\liminf$ and not $\limsup$", but both work, so it's fine :)

Comment: The liminf could be $-\infty$ and the limsup could be $\infty$ so I don't think it quite works.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\{Y_n\}_n$ be a sequence of $\sigma(X)$-measurable simple functions converging pointwise to $Y$. You know that the result holds for simple functions so for each $n$ let $f_n$ be the corresponding Borel function such that $Y_n=f_n(X)$. That $\{Y_n\}_n$ converges pointwise this tells us that $\{f_n\}_n$ converges pointwise on $X(\Omega)$. Now let $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ denote the Borel measurable set of the points $s\in \mathbb{R}$ for which $\{f_n(s)\}_n$ converges pointwise (we just showed that $X(\Omega)\subset A)$. Then we can define the Borel function $f:=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathcal{X}_Af_n$, and by simply taking pointwise limits on both sides of the equality $Y_n=f_n(X)$ we see that $Y=f(X)$.

Comment: why is $A$ necessarily a Borel set?

Comment: @PorkingBun$A=\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^\infty \bigcup\limits_{N=1}^\infty \bigcap\limits_{n,m\geq N}  \{x\in\Omega : |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<1/k\}.$